# Remove figure numerotation

Tags: floats, subfloats, labels

I tried to put two images side by side on my front page (so without caption), and this is how I did. The result is good but the problem is that, even if there's no caption, the next figure in my document starts as "Figure 2". It seems that, even without caption, my figure is still taken into account. How could I fix this ?

Thanks in advance,

Adrien

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{Logo Mammouths.PNG}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{Logo CAP.png}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi. It's is normal on this site to "accept" (and upvote) the most helpful answer. This is the way to say "thanks". In addition, it shows future readers which answer was the one that considered most helpful by you. Please consider doing that - the same is true for your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the figure numbering, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\setcounter{figure}{0} % <-- Important part!

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{example-image}
\caption{The numbering is correct}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks for your fast and complete answer !

Answer (score 2):

The real reason the issue you've encountered arises is because you are abusing and mis-using the `figure` and `subfigure` machinery. Running an instruction such as `\setcounter{figure}{0}` is the equivalent to applying a band-aid. Wouldn't it be nicer to avoid accidents that cause bleeding?

Why do I say that you're abusing the `figure` and `subfigure` machinery? There are two clear signs. First, by applying the `[H]` placement specifier, you're making sure the `figure` object won't "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word). But the floating mechanism for `table` and `figure` objects is one of the main reasons for even using these objects. Second, you don't provide `\caption` directives anywhere in the `figure` or `subfigure` environments. The captioning mechanism is the second main reason for using `table` and `figure` environments.

Thus, instead of writing

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{example-image-a}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

you really ought to be writing

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill % <-- new
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
```

or, better still,

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.47\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
```

Moral of the story: Don't use `figure` (and `subfigure`) environments unless you have to.

Comment: And are minipages really needed in the last code?

Comment: @egreg - The `minipage` wrappers may or may not be needed. I was assuming that the OP had a reason for using them with the `b` positioning specifier, so that's why I didn't get rid of them. For sure, if the images end up having the same heights, there would be no need for the `minipage` wrappers. Instead, one could just write `\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{...}` directly.